# Java - connection to ServerSocket via browser/URL

Tags: java, sockets, url, browser, serversocket

I'm writing a piece of software, and I'm under the restriction of not being able to use socket to connect to a java application using a ServerSocket.

I thought I'd try with an URL connection, since it's possible to define which port to connect to

e.g:

```
127.0.0.1:62666
```

I have my server app listening for connections and writing the input out to a jTextArea. When connecting to the server (127.0.0.1:62666) through a browser, it outputs:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
```

I have another app for connecting to the ServerSocket through an URL connection:

```
try{
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:62666");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.print("Hello");
        System.out.println("should have worked");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It prints out the "should have worked" message fyi, but it never writes anything to the jTextArea of the server. The code for the server app looks like this:

```
try{

        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(62666);

        while(doRun){
            Socket sock = serverSock.accept();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());

            InfoReader.gui.writeToTextArea(reader.readLine() + " From IP: " + sock.getInetAddress() + "\n");
            writer.println("Testing123");

            writer.close();

            reader.close();

        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note: when connecting through the browser it displays the text "Testing123".

So I'm wondering how to do this the way I'm trying or perhaps read the URL that the ServerSocket was accessed through, so I could access it through a URL while passing it arguments (in the URL).

Hope this makes sense :)

Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use a socket connection... You realize that every TCP connection, including URLConnection, uses a socket, right?

Comment: does the server recieve the message?

Comment: @ryan: I realize that. It's hard to explain. Short story: not allowed to instantiate Socket objects directly myself. 

@john: no it does not. It seems that the server gets "stuck" whenever I run the app that's supposed to connect to it. Whenever I try to connect to the ServerSocket *afterwards* via a browser, it just keeps on trying to connect.

Comment: Mike, did you ever find a way out of this? I'm interested to know what you found out or chose to do.

Comment: I never found a way that worked using URL. For what I'm doing, I'm not allowed to instantiate socket objects as of yet, so I'm pretty much coming up short.. Thanks for the interest :)

Comment: @MikeHaye - you're not using the http protocol. The `GET /  ...` message you get from the browser is part of the HTTP protocol. If I understand correctly, the question is how to read the URL when connecting to a serversocket from a browser.

Comment: Oh, and the slash that you get after the GET is the arguments of the URL. If you'd connected from the browser with this url: `127.0.0.1:62666/aaa`, you would have seen `GET /aaa ...`.

Answer (score 2):

There is one very good [example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ru/2015/06/how-to-create-http-server-in-java-serversocket-example.html):

```
public class SimpleHTTPServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
        while (true) {
            try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
                Date today = new Date();
                String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + today;
                socket.getOutputStream().write(httpResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ from browser and you'll get current date.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out exactly what's up. There's something funny about that OutputStream. Add a

```
((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
```

somewhere after `connect()` and before `close()`, and you should see something different, if not what you expect.

Perhaps instead of trying to use HTTP as a hack, you should just go full HTTP. Use HTTP from the client like you already are, and set up an embedded HTTP server on the server. There are several to choose from out there that literally take just a few lines to get running: [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/docbkx2.0/html/quickstart.html), [Simple Framework](http://www.simpleframework.org/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php), or [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty), for instance.

Comment: This outputs: POST / HTTP/1.1 From IP: /127.0.0.1

So, basically POST / HTTP/1.1. (the IP part was added by me).

I'm considering making the server application full on HTTP like you say, if it's that easy. I'd rather avoid it though, if this leads anywhere.

Comment: @Mike: I haven't found it to lead anywhere. If you put your readLine() into a loop, you'll end up printing out a full HTTP request, but your "Hello" line is mysteriously absent. No matter what I've tried, it seems like anything you write to that OutputStream yourself just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need to do if you want the client to send a message to the server using a URL connection:

```
public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        try
        {
            url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:62666");
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            writer.println("Hello World!");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Now heres the server:

```
public class Server implements Runnable
{
    public Server()
    {
        ServerSocket server = new Server(62666);
        client = server.accept();
        new Thread(this).start();  
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            String message;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()))
            while((message=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("Message from client: "+message);
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Client disconnected");
        }
    }
    Socket client;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this should work :/.. Basically the same that I'm doing, if you look carefully at what I posted. Don't see any major differences. Thanks though.

Comment: @Mike Haye if *you* look carefully you will see at least two major differences. He has omitted doOutput(true) hut there is another.

Comment: @EJP: The only differences I see are that this code has several syntax errors and it fails because doOutput is false. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart so you missed the print/println difference.

Comment: @EJP: I didn't miss it. It doesn't make a difference. Try it.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart it is missing from the 'only differences I see' above.

Comment: @EJP: Sorry, I should have said "the only differences I see in running this code"

Comment: Well the reason the server wasnt recieving the message was because the server never called reader.readLine(); there was no way for the server to read the message.

Answer (score 0):

```
writer.println("Hello");
```

You're not sending any newline. Also your 'should have worked' trace is in the wrong place. Should be after the flush().

Also you aren't reading the response.

Also the server is only going to display POST ... Or PUT ..., not the line you're sending. So this is never going to work unless you (a) make the server HTTP-conscious or (b) get rid of this insane restriction that you can't use a Socket. *Why* can't you use a Socket?

EDIT: my version of your code follows:

```
    static class Server implements Runnable
    {

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(62666);
                for (;;)
                {
                    Socket sock = serverSock.accept();
                    System.out.println("From IP: " + sock.getInetAddress());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("\t:" + line);
                    }
                    writer.println("Testing123");
                    writer.close();
                    reader.close();
                    System.out.println("Server exiting");
                    serverSock.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static class Client implements Runnable
    {

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:62666");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
//              connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.connect();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                writer.println("Hello");
                writer.flush();
                System.out.println("flushed");
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                writer.close();
                BufferedReader  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println("closed");
                System.out.println("response code="+responseCode);
                String  line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println("client read "+line);
                reader.close();
                System.out.println("Client exiting");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void  main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread  t = new Thread(new Server());
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
        new Client().run();
        System.out.println("Main exiting");
    }
```

Comment: That was my first thought, too, but it's not the problem.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart there are bigger problems that the println here. That server cannot possibly display that data.

Comment: Can you explain why? I'm at a loss. Where is the "Hello" going?

Comment: @Ryan Stewart because it only read and printed one line, which was the first HTTP header. It needs to read and display until readLine() returns null. NB *not* just until readLine() returns an empty line: that only indicates the end of the headers. Your "Hello" is next.

Comment: Have you actually run the program? In the form posted in the question, it doesn't output anything because it never sends anything. With a couple of changes, you can get it to both send and receive a complete HTTP request, but "Hello" never appears anywhere.

Comment: Yes I have, and with the println() correction and the server reading everything to EOS, the server sees everything down to and including "Hello". However as that isn't an HTTP server, it doesn't return valid HTTP so getResponseCode() stalls at the client. The point of the exercise remains entirely obscure. If you can't use a Socket you have to use a higher-level transport, which makes the Server incorrect.

Comment: @Ran Stewart yes and that's one of several reasons why it will never work. Nothing is actually written by HttpURLConnection until you do some input, either via getResponseCode() or by reading the input stream. But there are much bigger problems than that here.

Comment: Wait, you said that "Hello" showed up? Can you post some code that exhibits that behavior? I've yet to see that work, which is kind of the point of this whole thing.