# Adding url style path mapping to server/client socket connections

Tags: java, sockets, url, mapping, endpoint

so I came across this guy's website and he had a simple server/client socket example. Here is the server code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;

public class HelloWorldServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(5555);
        Socket socket = listener.accept();
        PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("hello world");

        socket.close();

        listener.close();
    }
}
```

and the client code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class HelloWorldClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String answer = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("response: " + "\"" + answer +"\"");
    }
}
```

How can i modify it so that I can define a url style path for this socket connection? for Example, i want this socket to be located on localhost:5555/HelloWorld, kind of like a servlet style mapping.

Is this possible with just plain sockets? 
thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726745/java-connection-to-serversocket-via-browser-url

Comment: so i  saw how to connect to a path, but how can i start my server on a specific path?

Comment: I'm confused now, start your server? The only place where you can start your server is the machine its running on - aka localhost / 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

The path mappings only apply to HTTP, which is the protocol your browser uses to get web pages. So you can't bind this to a specific URL. You can only bind it to a server.

If you want to write a web application with java, look into [Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/index.html). That has everything you need for web applications.